# create-react-app unsupported node version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I'm trying to create a new ReactJS app with create-react-app on Ubuntu 18.10. When I run `create-react-app myapp` I get the following note:

> Note: the project was bootstrapped with an old unsupported version of
>   tools. Please update to Node >=6 and npm >=3 to get supported tools in
>   new projects.

But when I check my node version with `node -v` I get v10.13.0 and checking npm with `npm -v` shows 6.4.1. `create-react-app --version` shows 2.1.1. So both my Node version and npm version are greater than the versions specified.

I'm not sure what to do with this since my versions are already above the versions specified. Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: try prepending `npx` to your command: `npx create-react-app myapp`

Comment: I tried adding npx and got the same note.

Comment: Remember that Stackoverflow is your "I ran out of places to ask" last resort, so the very first place to check would be https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues (do some searching, if you find nothing, file it, and then the create-react-app folks can help figure out whether it's a problem in their code, or in your setup).

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if there is any linkering node_modules/ folder in the path or in the root folder and try to remove that before running the command.

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same. I have just cut and paste the my-app folder to my home directory and found solution. You can do the same or reinstall it to your home directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of installing create-react-app as globally, you can create a new react project with `npx create-react-app myapp`.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I installed node on ubuntu using snap. When I uninstalled the snap version and used nvm to install instead, I no longer got that error.